# Set UIView height to fit UILabel subview using autolayouts

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, constraints, subview

### What I try to do

I have custom UIView with a UILabel as subview in it. I want the UIView to wrap the UILabel height and set it´s height depending of the text length. The UILabel is resizing it´s height correctly when adding text to label.text. So far so good.

### Problem

The UIView is not adjusting height by the UILabel content. The text should be inside the white UIView below. This should be possible to solve by constraints, correct? I can´t get it right though. Can this be done purely with Storyboard or do I have to manually set the UIView height in code?

[image]

The result:
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do it in storyboard. I'm doing it all the time. You should check if you have set for your UILabel the number of lines to zero. In that way you allow for unlimited number of lines making possible for the view to grow to accommodate the content.

Comment: Yes the UILabel is set to: label.numberOfLines = 0. How do I set the constraints between the UILabel and UIView? Im guessing the problem should be there?

Comment: No, the constraints between your label and "Available Bookings Header" view looks ok. How do you set the constraints between "Available Bookings Header" view and it's superview?

Comment: Available Bookings Header is placed in tableView.tableHeaderView. Im using it as a table header. Ok, any other suggestions? :(

Comment: How do you put your "Available Bookings Header" into your tableView header? How do you set the frame size for "Available Bookings Header"? What view controller do you have (UIViewContoroller, UITableViewController)? Can you put (just for test) the "Available Bookings Header" view directly in your view controllers view and set just the top, leading and trailing constraint? In such way your content should grow.

Comment: var header = AvailableBookingsTableHeader.instanceFromNib() as! AvailableBookingsTableHeader self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header

Comment: I don´t set the frame for AvailableBookingsTableHeader, thats the thing I want autolayouts do for me? I just tested to move AvailableBookingsTableHeader to a blank view and a TestViewController. Same problem, so the AvailableBookingsTableHeader parent view is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Content Hugging Property of your UILabel superview in Interface Builder to 1000:

[image]

Comment: Sorry m8, it did no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `label` constraints to the `UIView` is correct. I just tested it.

My guess is that the `UIView`, constraints have been set with either a height constraint or a top and bottom constraint to its parent view. This would result in the `UIView` that is holding the label not to be able to increase its size. Try removing the appropriate constraints.

If is not, can you show the part where the `UIView` constraints to its parent.

Comment: Thx Zac but the UIView has no constraints to it parent view. The UIView is meant to have as tableView.tableHeaderView but I also tried to add it to a blank TestViewController and add it as subview to the main view. Still not resizing..